# Vue.js animation: Enter after Leave and not simultaneously

Tags: vue.js, animation

I have two components and a fade-in/fade-out animation set up for them.
For a brief moment, both components exist on the page at different opacities, and the scrollbar shows up and disappears.
Is there a way to avoid this? A way to start the fade-in animation only after the fade-out animation is done?

**The Animation:**

```
.view-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out, transform 0.5s ease;
}

.view-enter-active {
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out, transform 0.5s ease;
    transition-delay: 0.5s; /* Increasing this doesn't seem to work */
}

.view-enter, .view-leave-to {
    opacity: 0.5; /* It should be 1, but setting it to 0.5 allows you to see exactly what's happening */
}

.view-enter-to, .view-leave {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Any help would be very much appriciated!

Comment: You should share the code where you are displaying the components

Comment: You can use [transition modes](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Modes) to specify how two elements can be toggled between each other.

Comment: @Terry Wow that was simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To further elaborate on my comment: [VueJS transition components support the `mode` property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Modes), where you can specify the sequence of transitions when toggling between two elements.

Since you do not want both elements to appear at the same time when one is transitioning in while the other is transitioning out, you should be using:

```
mode="out-in"
```

Based on the documentation:

> `out-in`: Current element transitions out first, then when complete, the new element transitions in.